# Mongoose CastError (Cast to ObjectId failed)

Tags: mongoose

While testing my API routes in Postman;

**I got this error:**

```js
"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"632aa0c8930ca0decc7d042b\\n\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""
```

**Here is the controller and route part of the update API:**

**routes:**

```js
app.put("/api/users/:id", authorization, UserController.updateUser);
```

**controller:**

```js
updateUser: async (req, res) => {      
        try {
            const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {new:true, runValidators:true});
            res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
        } catch(err) {
            res.status(500).json(err)
        }
}
```

**Here is the error shown in Postman:**

```js
{
    "stringValue": "\"632aa0c8930ca0decc7d042b\\n\"",  
    "valueType": "string",  
    "kind": "ObjectId",  
    "value": "632aa0c8930ca0decc7d042b\n",  
    "path": "_id",  
    "reason": {},  
    "name": "CastError",  
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"632aa0c8930ca0decc7d042b\\n\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""
}
```

What can go wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It says that; you try to `findById` and the Id variable has to be an `ObjectId`. But your value is a `string`

So, you can convert your string to `ObjectId` like `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)`:

```js
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id), req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true });
```

If the Id parameter always comes with **"\n"**, you need to `split` it, separate the Id, and then use the Id by converting to an `ObjectId` into the **findByIdAndUpdate** query like this:

```js
const [parameter] = req.params.id.split("\");
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(parameter), req.body, { new: true, runValidators: true });
```

I hope it is helpful for you. If it doesn't, please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Onur. It worked with the solution that you provided. Here is my final code snippet,         
                                                                                                                                            
 const parameter = req.params.id;
            
 const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(parameter.split("\n")[0]), req.body, {new:true, runValidators:true})

Comment: You're welcome Ayesha. I am so glad to can be helpful to you. Good luck..